# Click on list view and and let it selected - android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking for something in which

For eg. if i click on the list item... the view stay selected. is that possible?

I want this because... the content of the view is large so i have set marquee property to the textview, and that will only work if I list view is selected. so I want something...

If user click on view it stays selected

Thank you.

Comment: selected means you want to change color of that view on click and color remains of that view till other view has been clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. On the callback fired when you press on a item you can invoke:

[View.setSelected(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSelected%28boolean%29)